# How to use blueimp-file-upload with webpack?

Tags: jquery-file-upload, webpack

I'm using blueimp-file-upload in my website, and I'm using webpack to organize my js code.

I installed blueimp-file-upload and jquery.ui.widget from NPM

```
npm install --save blueimp-file-upload
npm install --save jquery.ui.widget
```

and I require blueimp-file-upload in my entry file

```
require('blueimp-file-upload')
```

but when I run webpack, I get thie error:

```
ERROR in ./~/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery.ui.widget' in E:\app-parent\cooka-common-web\src\main\resources\static\node_modules\blueimp-file-upload\js
@ ./~/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js 19:8-22:19
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Disable both AMD and CommonJS and use the Browser Global jQuery.

```js
/* The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included */
require('imports?define=>false&exports=>false!blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js');
/* The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads */
require('imports?define=>false&exports=>false!blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js');
/* The basic File Upload plugin */
require('imports?define=>false&exports=>false!blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js');
/* The File Upload processing plugin */
require('imports?define=>false&exports=>false!blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js');
/* The File Upload validation plugin */
require('imports?define=>false&exports=>false!blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js');
/* The File Upload Angular JS module */
require('imports?define=>false&exports=>false!blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-angular.js');
```

This is the configuration I'm using to integrate webpack, blueimp-fileupload with angular. Alternatively you can configure in your webpack.config.js as a regex to avoid repeating loaders.

Comment: It might also be good to note that you can provide jquery to blueimp by using the provide plugin: `webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
      })`. more info [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html)

Comment: as an additional note, the "imports" loader is needed: `npm i --save-dev imports-loader`

Comment: what is the "Browser Global jQuery"?

Comment: Browser Global jQuery means jQuery is available on window namespace.

Comment: I was using all the bells and whistles and had an issue with dependency order with this. Found `script-loader`. Might help someone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48236429/1447679

Answer (score 22):

### If you're working with images:

Webpack was complaining about some modules that weren't in the blueimp-file-upload package. Here is the way I got this working:

#### Install missing dependencies:

```
npm i -S blueimp-load-image
npm i -S blueimp-canvas-to-blob
```

#### Configure Webpack:

```
config.resolve = {
   extensions: ['', '.js'],
   alias: {
      'load-image': 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image.js',
      'load-image-meta': 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-meta.js',
      'load-image-exif': 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-exif.js',
      'canvas-to-blob': 'blueimp-canvas-to-blob/js/canvas-to-blob.js',
      'jquery-ui/widget': 'blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js'
   }
};
```

#### Include scripts in your app:

```
import "blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js";
import "blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js";
import "blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js";
import "blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works fine. I needed to add this line to resolve -> alias as well: `'load-image-scale': 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-scale.js',`

Comment: This answer was the most helpful to me. But the most recent version needs the `load-image-scale` alias, like Yolo said. Besides that, you need to change the `jquery-ui/widget` alias to `jquery-ui/ui/widget`.

Comment: Latest version of webpack doesn't like that `config.resolve.extensions[0]` https://stackoverflow.com/a/42377085/684776

Comment: i also had to add `'load-image-orientation': 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-orientation.js'`

Comment: We had to add a couple of more aliases:

alias: {
        'load-image': 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image.js',
        'load-image-meta': 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-meta.js',
        'load-image-exif': 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-exif.js',
        'load-image-orientation': 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-orientation.js',
        'load-image-scale': 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-scale.js',
        'canvas-to-blob': 'blueimp-canvas-to-blob/js/canvas-to-blob.js',
        'jquery-ui/ui/widget': 'blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js'
      },

Answer (score 8):

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js'],
    alias: {
        'jquery-ui/widget': 'blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js'
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Newer versions of this library need this line instead:

`'jquery-ui/ui/widget': 'blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js'`

Answer (score 5):

I had almost identical problem, except that Error announced not 'jquery.ui.widget' but 'jquery/ui/widget'.
For me @Gowrav answer was wrong way.

After days of straying I've solved it in the simple way. Just did:

```
npm install jquery-ui
```

The fact is that jquery.fileupload.js searching for its vendor:
[image: jquery.fileupload.js]

But in context where jquery.fileupload.js is trying to import dependency, of course, it can't be found (resolved). So I add it to project instead.

P.S. It's just my opinion about how does all work. But this way has helped me.

Answer (score 2):

`jquery.fileupload.js` checks for AMD require first which results in this error. You can teach webpack not to use AMD style for this file. (Make sure to `npm install imports-loader` for this method to work.):

```
require('imports?define=>false!blueimp-file-upload')
```

It should correctly register the module as CommonJS and will require the `jquery.ui.widget` from the right location.

Read more here: http://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#disable-some-module-styles

Comment: I tried to use imports-loader, but inside `jquery.fileupload.js` file, it only require `jquery` and `jquery.ui.widget`, but I need require more additional file, like `tmpl.min.js` `load-image.all.min.js` `canvas-to-blob.min.js` `jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js` `jquery.iframe-transport.js` `jquery.fileupload.js` `jquery.fileupload-process.js` `jquery.fileupload-image.js` `jquery.fileupload-validate.js` `jquery.fileupload-ui.js`   what should I do? (the demo from offical site require all files I mentioned)

Comment: Although I did not try myself it looks like many of those you listed are modules you can find here: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=blueimp

Comment: only part of the modules can be found on npm,
files like `jquery.fileupload-process.js` is in the same folder as `jquery.fileupload.js`, I do not know how to require it.

`require('imports?define=>false!blueimp-file-upload/jquery.fileupload-process.js')` is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an alias to jquery.ui.widget's main file - it unfortunately doesn't specify one in its package.json, so webpack can't find it otherwise.

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        "jquery.ui.widget": "node_modules/jquery.ui.widget/jquery.ui.widget.js"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

first install two plugins

```
npm i blueimp-file-upload --save
npm i jquery-ui --save
```

then require in web pack

```
require('blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload')
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you can solve this by changing your webpack config, just add the path to resolve (for example I am using bower)

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [ '', '.js', '.jsx' ],
    modulesDirectories: [
       'node_modules',
       'bower_components', 
       'bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor' 
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In webpack 3.x, the syntax will look like this:

```
  {
    test: require.resolve("blueimp-file-upload"),
    use: "imports-loader?define=>false"
  }
```