# Why does webpack need an empty extension

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to figure out why webpack requires this empty extension.

Inside `resolve.extensions` there's always this kind of configuration:

```
extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
```

Why can't it be just this:

```
extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
```

Comment: also see here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3043

Comment: I believe you're using webpack 1. Upgrading should fix it.

https://webpack-gatsby.netlify.com/how-to/upgrade-from-webpack-1/#resolve-extensions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions):

> Setting this option will override the default, meaning that webpack will no longer try to resolve modules using the default extensions. If you want modules that were required with their extension (e.g. `require('./somefile.ext')`) to be properly resolved, you **must** include an empty string in your array. Similarly, if you want modules that were required without extensions (e.g. `require('underscore')`) to be resolved to files with “.js” extensions, you **must** include `".js"` in your array.

In other words, if you didn't include the empty string and required a module as `./foo.js`, webpack would look for `./foo.js.js` and `./foo.js.jsx` instead.

Answer (score 24):

In a newer Webpack Version you can't use an empty string. It says:

`Getting error: configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty`.

You have to use `extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']` or `extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']`.

Issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3043

Comment: true story "webpack": "^2.6.1"

Comment: But wouldn't the * matches all file because it is a wildcard character? For example we know that happy.js will match .js but both unhappy.qs and happy.js will also match * since * is a wildcard character. We don't want unhappy.qs because we didn't really want file with the .qs extension

Answer (score 7):

This has been modified now in webpack2.

Now you have to provide only:

```
resolve: {extensions: ['.js', '.es6']}
```

And if you provide `''` in the array it throws the error:

> configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty

Answer (score 4):

The `''` extension is only really necessarily if you [require a file by its full name](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions):

> If you want modules that were required with their extension (e.g. `require('./somefile.ext')`) to be properly resolved, you **must** include an empty string in your array.

Webpack will always use one of the `extensions` while trying to find a file, along the lines of:

```
var fileName = nameGiven + extension[i];
fs.exists(fileName, ...);
```

If the `nameGiven` includes the full file name, for example `require('./foo.js')`, it'll still append each extension:

```
'./foo.js' + '.js'  // './foo.js.js'  duplicated extension
'./foo.js' + '.jsx' // './foo.js.jsx' mixed extensions
```

Compared to:

```
'./foo.js' + ''     // './foo.js'     left as-is
```