# import Blueimp jQuery File Upload in webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack, blueimp

i'm importing file like this

```
import "blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js";
import "blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js";
import "blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js";
import "blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js";
```

and altered webpack config with

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'load-image': 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image.js',
        'load-image-meta': 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-meta.js',
        'load-image-exif': 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-exif.js',
        'load-image-scale': 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-scale.js',
        'canvas-to-blob': 'blueimp-canvas-to-blob/js/canvas-to-blob.js',
        'jquery-ui/ui/widget': 'blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js'
    }
}
```

inspired by this: [How to use blueimp-file-upload with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849476/how-to-use-blueimp-file-upload-with-webpack/32114670)

it is compiling ok, but i get error in browser console

```
app.js:1391 TypeError: $(...).fileupload is not a function
```

jQuery is defined globally
looks like fileupload plugin is not registered. i don't get it.

Comment: Did you solve this by chance? Having the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I too had a difficult time trying to get this to work. I gave up on `import` statements and used `require` instead. At first, I tried to use [imports-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader) with require. Before I forget, I think you can solve your immediate problem by adding the following to your `webpack.config.js` in the appropriate place:

```
module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": 'jquery'
    })      
]);
```

This caused me other issues as I already had `jQuery` loaded as a static asset on the site, and my module was being injected within it.

But back to my resolution to avoid all of this pain.

With `imports-loader`, the problem is the load order of dependencies and I couldn't get `webpack` and `babel` to behave. Then I discovered [script-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/script-loader/)

Install `script-loader`

```
> npm install --save-dev script-loader
```

I was then able to remove my alias resolves as they were no longer needed. Working like a charm. Would love to hear any suggestions on a better method.

Example: **main.js**

```
require('script-loader!blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js');
require('script-loader!blueimp-tmpl/js/tmpl.js');
require('script-loader!blueimp-load-image/js/load-image.all.min.js');
require('script-loader!blueimp-canvas-to-blob/js/canvas-to-blob.js');
require('script-loader!blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js');
require('script-loader!blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js');
require('script-loader!blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js');
require('script-loader!blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js');
require('script-loader!blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js');
require('script-loader!blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-video.js');
require('script-loader!blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js');
require('script-loader!blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js');
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. Just copy paste and it worked.

Comment: I'd love to know why this is needed, for a modern and maintained library... nonetheless, thank you :)